# Афропати или афро-пати?

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис

Афропати или афро-пати? Через дефис или слитно?

Answer (score 2):

*Африканская вечеринка*, если слово образовано от сочетания прилагательное+существительное, то пишется слитно.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что надо писать афро-пати. "Афро" это определение к слову "пати"(а не сложное слово с первой основой "афро"),  причем оба слова уже достаточно освоились в языке. Есть афро-румба, есть пати-вечеринка (тематическая тусовка). Если мы будем считать  "пати" полноправным существительным (а скорее всего, нам скоро придется так считать), то  это дефисное написание  в соответсвии с существующими правилами, для сравнения:арт-дизайн, гала-представление, джаз-оркестр.

При слитном же написании вторая основа "пати" просто "теряется" и не передает свое смысловое значение: кажется, что перед нами простое, а не сложное слово.

Сейчас в языке идут интересные процессы под влиянием английской грамматики. Мне кажется, скоро придется узаконить не только "афро-пати, но и "афро пати", по аналогии с широко распространенным раздельным написанием "онлан трансляция", хотя правилами рекомендуется "онлайн-трансляция".

Answer (score 0):

Прочитав ваши разъяснения, я зашел в тупик. Я всегда считал слово "онлайн" наречием (отвечает на вопрос "как?") и, следовательно, раздельное написание правильным. Пожалуйста, разъясните мне каким правилом нужно руководствоваться.

Comment: Грамота-ру дает два варианта:  онлайн - неизм. (наречие) и онлайн как первая часть сложных слов с дефисным написанием. Наречия в русском языке могут выполнять определительную функцию,например: дом напротив, концерт онлайн. В качестве приложения онлайн пишется через дефис: онлайн-концерт. И всё чаще можно встретить "онлайн концерт" - своеобразный "английский" вариант записи. В русском языке приложение может писаться раздельно, но тогда оно должно склоняться: богатырь всадник - богатыря всадника, но чудо-гриб (несклоняемый вариант пишется через дефис).